French or Scandinavian movie about deaf teenage runaways

Foreign film, most likely french or Scandinavian
Based on two deaf teenagers 
Romantic movie the boy is being bullied in school, he also happens to be on the water-polo team, the girls family doesn't understand her and they argue among themselves even though she can read lips 
They run away and live an abandon ship or a submarine that has been ran aground
the sex scene in the movie uses paint, they start throwing pink paint at each other and then have sex
she gets pregnant and starts writing a book, the boy asks if she will love the child more than she loves him and then he starts going crazy 

That's all I got I hope its enough to help someone identity this movie I have been searching for years since I've seen it and can't find a thing it was a movie that I watched a couple weeks after my first viewing of Ben-X which is an amazing movie if you haven't seen it. 

Sounds like the Dutch film 170 Hz from 2011.

Nick and Evy are two adolescents who fall hopelessly in love with each other. Their love has no voice or sound as they are both deafmute. They have their own ways of communicating with each other, so while being in love already makes them stand apart from the rest of the world, in the splendid isolation of their soundless love they distance themselves from their surroundings even more. When they sense that their parents do not fully agree with them being together, they develop an audacious plan: they will flee and hide in a special place, where Evy will become pregnant and have a baby - they are convinced that once they have a child together nothing and nobody will be able to keep them apart. Nick takes the initiative and drives off with Evy to the hiding place he has meticulously prepared, the wreck of a former Soviet submarine in a distant part of the harbour. Within that metal casing full of sounds and tremors they cannot hear, but with their strongly developed remaining senses, can feel all the more. They concentrate on their baby project. But in that cage of happiness Evy slowly discovers that Nick had another reason to disappear.

Here's the trailer (where you can briefly see the scene with the pink paint):




I love you this is the move! this is the movie I've been trying to find for 5 years! thank you so much! I though I was good at knowing about movies especially since I have an extensive amount that I've watched that I remember very well this has been the only movie that has escaped me in terms of the name. I saw literally 6 seconds of the trailer and I knew this is the movie the fight between the parents basically is what was like DING THAT ITS!
